# How to prevent windows shutdown while one particular app is open

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-store-apps

Need help to parmanetly disable the "Shutdown anyway button" while shutting down the pc.

or any batch file or application that stop the computer to shutdown while one particular app is open.

Means computer will not turn off while that particular app is opne untill I close that app.

pls suggest

Tried registry tweaks but not working

Comment: [`Very first Google result`](https://asapguide.com/automatically-shutdown-anyway/)

Comment: That is not working

Answer (score 0):

You just need this batch code:

```
tasklist | find /i "application.exe" >NUL && shutdown -a
```

Put the application you want to select instead of "application".
The "tasklist" command will display all current running tasks in your system, and you need to use " | find /i" to search for a certain string (use /i to use case insensitive mode). The code after "&&" will be executed only if the code actually finds something (">NUL" is used to hide the output)